# Sum multiple fields with select new and where raises error 'Model' does not have definition of 'Sum'

Tags: c#, linq

First timer to C# and want to see if i can change a query. Basically, I want an aggregated values of the two currency columns in one go. There are Car dealer, with each dealer having a list of cars in their possession. So I want to get list of car dealers along with a total cost of all the cars under them. For now what I am doing is I loop over each dealer, get the cars then loop the cars over summing each cars price, which sounds inefficient to me.

```
public object DealerObj(Dealer d)
{
    var cars = d.DealerCars.Select(cc => new { cc.Cost }).ToList();

    var totalCost decimal = 0;
    foreach (var car in cars){
        totalCost += car.Cost;
    }

    return new {
        d.DealerName,
        totalCost = totalCost
    }
}
```

While I am getting the correct results, the query appears slower. Is there a way to do a Sum() on the results and avoid the loop, something like below

```
   var cars = d.DealerCars.Select(cc => new { total = cc.Sum(s=>s.Cost) });
```

Comment: `cc` is `Model`, not `IEnumerable<Model>`.

Comment: It looks like even your top block of code is wrong - are you really getting a `car` object from the `cc.Cost` projection? Try `return d.DealerCars.ToList().Sum(c => c.Cost);`

Comment: Give us your `DealerCars` and  `Dealer` structure, please

Comment: @slugster No need for the `ToList` in there, as that will cause ti to iterate twice.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you just need to do this:

```
public object DealerObj(Dealer d)
{
    return new
    {
        d.DealerName,
        totalCost = d.DealerCars.Sum(cc => cc.Cost),
    };
}
```

It seems like a fairly pointless method. I would love to know how you are using the above code, espcially how you're turning the returned `object` into something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> There are Car dealer, with each dealer having a list of cars in their
>   possession. So I want to get list of car dealers along with a total
>   cost of all the cars under them.

The function that you posted and Enigmativity has correctly updated to get the sum would be used to iterate over a dealer at a time.

If you have a collection of Dealers outside of this method call, in this case a `List<Dealer>` as an example:

```
List<Dealer> dealers = loadDealers();
var sumObjects = dealers.Select(d => DealerObj(d)).ToList();
```

and with Enigmativity's change to get the Sum for the cars under the dealer, you would be good to go. Though I would recommend defining a suitable model (DTO or ViewModel) for this kind of summary rather than trying to pass anonymous types around and/or `object` references, and giving the method a more descriptive name.

If instead you want to run an operation across a dealers collection directly:

```
List<Dealer> dealers = loadDealers(); // Load these from data source.
var sumObjects = dealers
    .SelectMany(d => d.DealerCars)
    .GroupBy(c => c.Dealer.DealerName)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        DealerName = g.Key,
        TotalCost = g.Sum(c => c.Cost)
    }).ToList();
```

This assumes all dealers are uniquely named. If not, you would want to group by `c.Dealer` and then select `g.Key.Name` along with anything to differentiate the multiple dealers /w the same name.

If you're dealing with a list of dealer objects that are loaded as a whole into memory then I would probably stick with the method approach, as it's a bit cleaner to read and interpret what is going on.

Where the 2nd approach would come into play is if you are dealing with something that uses `IQueryable` such as Entity Framework to retrieve your data. The first approach would need to load all dealers AND their related details into memory entirely to work without a potentially significant performance hit if related details for each dealer needed to be lazy loaded after the fact. (Extra round trips to the DB) Using the 2nd approach against an `IQueryable` (DbSet / EF Linq expression) means that it can be translated down to SQL provided you follow some key rules, resulting in a single, far more efficient query to the database.

For instance: Given an EF context:

```
using(var context = new AppContext())
{
    var sumObjects = context.Dealers
        .SelectMany(d => d.DealerCars)
        .GroupBy(c => c.Dealer.DealerName)
        .Select(g => new 
        {
            DealerName = g.Key,
            TotalCost = g.Sum(c => c.Cost)
        }).ToList();
}
```

Alternatively for that to work efficiently with something like a repository method, that repository would need to return `IQueryable<Dealer>` rather than `IEnumerable<Dealer>`. EF will only compose these down to an efficient query if using `IQueryable`. If you use `IEnumerable` the query will be executed before these criteria are considered and you would potentially be facing lazy load hits.

If your methods are using `IEnumerable<Dealer>` or `List<Dealer>` or arrays etc. and no idea or need for `IQueryable` then sticking with the method per Dealer will probably be the easiest to follow.

Answer (score -1):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8)

> Computes the sum of a sequence of numeric values

So you can only `Sum()` for `IEnumerable<Cost>` like below.

```
var totalCost = d.DealerCars.Sum(p => p.Cost });

/* From my point of view, you should where the condition from your parameter
var totalCost = d.DealerCars.Where(p => p.DealerID == d.DealerID) 
                            .Sum(p => p.Cost }); */
return new { d.DealerName, totalCost = totalCost }
```

Comment: Why do `.Select(p => p.Cost }).Sum(p => p)` when `.Sum(p => p.Cost })` would suffice?

Comment: No, **Computes the sum of a sequence of numeric values.** While `.Sum(p => p.Cost })`  `p` is MODEL, not IEnumerable<Model>
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes, `p` is MODEL. That's fine. You can replace `.Select(p => p.Cost }).Sum(p => p)` with `.Sum(p => p.Cost)`.

Comment: ah okie, I've updated my answer, please take a look at.

Comment: Where did you get the need to do `p.DealerID == d.DealerID` from?

Comment: As you can see the param `Dealer `, So it's easy to guess. Yeah, From my point of view. Updated my answer, please take a look at @Enigmativity

Comment: It doesn't seem logical that a property under `Dealer` would have values for multiple dealers.

Comment: What do you think about `DealerCars`? Obviously, it combines between `Dealer` and `Cars`. So from the param `Dealer`, You should get total cost for it accordingly.

Comment: I think the OP is new to coding and has chosen a poor name for the property.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Anyway, I didn't know why I'm getting downvoting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Wede Asmera Tseada